# Keybinding in tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

If I type '*' in keyboard, it should be typed as 'x' in the entry field. Below is the sample code. I'm new to tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
def func(number):
    x = str(e1.get())
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e1.insert(0, str(x) + str('x'))
    
main = Tk()
main.geometry('200x50')
e1=Entry()
e1.bind('*',func)
e1.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Here I'm getting 'x*'. But I need only 'x' to be typed in the entry field. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: `e1.insert(0, str(x))` on behalf of `e1.insert(0, str(x) + str('x'))`?

Comment: Add `return 'break'` at the end of `func()` to ignore the entered `*` key.

Comment: @acw1668 It's working now. Thanks

Comment: @Renaud I got the answer from acw1668. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ignore the `*` character entered by returning `'break'` at the end of `func()`.  Also your logic will not work if the input cursor is not at the end of the input string.

Below is a modified `func()`:

```
def func(event):
    # add the "x" at the insertion position
    event.widget.insert('insert', 'x')
    # ignore the entered "*" character
    return 'break'
```